# Displaying SE Flair on my Facebook Timeline

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there any way I show off my Stack exchange Flair on my Facebook Timeline?

Pasting the HTML code snippet as a "Status Update" just gives a link to my SE Profile.

Also is there any way I can make it appear as the first post in Facebook for ever?

EDIT:
I am looking for some-kind of Facebook app to do this. There is no app to do any such thing but there may be apps which post whatever html code snippet you give and also dynamically update them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Stack Exchange support issue. Such questions should be asked at [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook doesn't allow updating a post content. So no app can help you with that. And only way to stick a post on your timeline is to make it featured. But as the post object cannot be updated, you just have to post it and feature it everytime your flair is updated. And also you have to post images of your flair as Facebook doesn't allow parsing HTML content on your timeline. You can render HTML on your App page (So if anyone visits your app, you can show them your flair), but not on your profile timeline.